# delete function not working in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, mysql, codeigniter

My delete function is not working. After clicking the confirm message it's not deleting.

My view looks like this:

```
<div id="selected-color" >
    <?php if ($this->session->userdata('edit_colors')) {
        foreach ($this->session->userdata('edit_colors') as $color)
        { ?>
            <div class="col-md-2 selected-color">
                <div class="color-box" style="background-color:<?php echo $color; ?>"></div>
                <div class="selected-color-btn" color='<?php echo $color; ?>' data-toggle="modal" >
                    <input type="hidden" name="color_id" value="<?php echo $color; ?>"> 
                    <a class="fa fa-close" data-toggle="modal" onclick='return deleteItem()'  name="delete" id="title" img="img1446224811.jpg" big-img=""  title="Delete" href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin_control/delete_color/<?php echo $result->id;?>/<?php echo $color;?>"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete"></i></a></span>
                </div>
            </div> 
        <?php 
        }
    }?>
</div>
        </div>
```

My javascript looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function deleteItem() {
        var checkstr = confirm('are you sure want to delete this?');
        if (!checkstr) {
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

My controller looks like this:

```
public function delete_color($id = null)
{ 
    $this->roxmodel->delete_color($id);
    redirect('admin_control/view_images');
}
```

My model looks like this:

```
public function delete_color($id)
{ 
    $this->db->where('product_color.id', $id);
    if ($this->db->delete('product_color'))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
}
```

My table looks like this:

```
 id | product_id |  color  |
----------------------------
711 |   341      | #f79646 |
712 |   341      | #31859b |
713 |   341      | #c0504d |
745 |   343      | #c0504d |
749 |   347      | #1f497d |
779 |   348      | #c0504d |
```

I guess my problem is in the anchor tag ...

my controler for edit function looks like this...

```
public function edit_gallery($id)
{
    $data['active_mn']='add_images';
   $data['active_mn']='view_images';


      if($_POST)
      {
           $this->form_validation->set_rules('image','Image','callback_is_upload_image');
           if($this->form_validation->run()==true)
           {
      if($this->roxmodel->image_update1())
            {
              $this->session->unset_userdata('image');
              //$this->session->unset_userdata('colors');
              $this->session->set_flashdata('message','updated successfully');
              redirect('admin_control/view_images');
            }
          else
            {
              $this->session->set_flashdata('message','update failed');
              redirect('admin_control/view_images');
            }
      }
    }
      if($id){
      $id=$this->uri->segment(3);
      $data['result']=$this->roxmodel->view_gallery_id($id);
      //$data['query']=$this->admin_model->get_all('products')->result();
     // $data['detail']=$this->roxmodel->get_products(null,null,$id);
      $colors=$this->roxmodel->get_product_color(null,$id)->result();
      if($colors)
        {
      foreach ($colors as $row){ $color[]=$row->color; }
      $this->session->set_userdata('edit_colors',$color);
        }
      $this->session->set_userdata('image',json_decode($data['result']->image));
      $data['category']=$this->roxmodel->get_super_category();


       $data['sub_category']=$this->roxmodel->get_sub_category();
      }

      $this->load->view('edit_image',$data);

  }
```

see my view there how can i get corresponding id value

Comment: Done any debugging yet? Throw in some `echo`s or `var_dump`s and `console.log`s to see where the problem is.

Comment: yes..whwn i did console.log it comes like this

Comment: try to echo your query and see if your query is actually getting executed echo $this->db->last_query();

Comment: Can you show the route being used in routes.php?

Answer (score 0):

See This is how I delete my records.
I have made a function in my Base Model like this:

```
    public function delete($id){
        $filter = $this->_primary_filter;
        $id = $filter($id);

        if (!$id) {
            return FALSE;
        }
        $this->db->where($this->_primary_key, $id);
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $this->db->delete($this->_table_name);
    }
```

Then In my Controller I initialize it like this :

```
    public function delete($id)
{
   $this->model->delete($id);
   redirect('admin/dashboard');
}
```

In View my Anchor tag :

```
<td><?php echo btn_delete('controller/delete/' . $user->id); ?></td>
```

Also have created a helper for edit and delete button:

```
function btn_delete ($uri)
{
    return anchor($uri, '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>', array(
        'onclick' => "return confirm('You are about to delete a record. This cannot be undone. Are you sure?');"
    ));
}
```

MY_Model.php

```
<?php
class MY_Model extends CI_Model {

protected $_table_name = '';
protected $_primary_key = 'id';
protected $_primary_filter = 'intval';
protected $_order_by = '';
public $rules = array();
protected $_timestamps = FALSE;

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

public function array_from_post($fields){
    $data = array();
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        $data[$field] = $this->input->post($field);
    }
    return $data;
}

public function array_from_get($fields){
    $data = array();
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        $data[$field] = $this->input->get($field);
    }
    return $data;
}


public function get($id = NULL, $single = FALSE){

    if ($id != NULL) {
        $filter = $this->_primary_filter;
        $id = $filter($id);
        $this->db->where($this->_primary_key, $id);
        $method = 'row';
    }
    elseif($single == TRUE) {
        $method = 'row';
    }
    else {
        $method = 'result';
    }


    return $this->db->get($this->_table_name)->$method();
}

public function get_by($where, $single = FALSE){
    $this->db->where($where);
    return $this->get(NULL, $single);
}

public function save($data, $id = NULL){




    // Set timestamps
    if ($this->_timestamps == TRUE) {
        $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $id || $data['created'] = $now;
        $data['modified'] = $now;
    }

    // Insert
    if ($id === NULL) {
        !isset($data[$this->_primary_key]) || $data[$this->_primary_key] = NULL;
        $this->db->set($data);
        $this->db->insert($this->_table_name);
        $id = $this->db->insert_id();
    }
    // Update
    else {
        $filter = $this->_primary_filter;
        $id = $filter($id);
        $this->db->set($data);
        $this->db->where($this->_primary_key, $id);
        $this->db->update($this->_table_name);
    }

    return $id;
}

public function delete($id){
    $filter = $this->_primary_filter;
    $id = $filter($id);

    if (!$id) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    $this->db->where($this->_primary_key, $id);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $this->db->delete($this->_table_name);
}
```

}

Comment: what is the purpose of _primary_filter

Comment: In You case you wont need this @MOHAMMED

Comment: thanks..but my problem is iam not getting the corresponding id in anchor tag

Comment: @MOHAMMED did you extend you model to MY_Model.php ? also you should create a file named MY_Model.php  in application/core and extend the MY_Model to CI_Model

Comment: @MOHAMMED create a file in your helpers folder and add the function btn_delete code in it

Answer (score -2):

*add this in model *

`return $this->db->affected_rows();`

*and this to controller*

`$r=$this->model->delete($id);
print_r($r);`

*and give me back the result*

Comment: Looking at his functions it should be straight forward his function is expecting a parameter and that your method isnt sending the ID along at all.

Comment: $route['default_controller'] = 'roxcontrol';
$route['404_override'] = '';

Comment: @vb still having same problem the page is redirecting but not getting deleted

Comment: its reloading to the page nothing got deleted

Comment: *Can you tell me what this* `print_r($r)` displays you on screen ?

Comment: nothing is displaying...public function delete_color($id=null)
{ 
    $r=$this->roxmodel->delete_color($id);
    print_r($r);
  
   redirect('admin_control/view_images');
}

Comment: comment the redirect line and than you will see what is displaying

Comment: please check if you are passing right id from controller to model 
just 
`print_r($id);` 
in your controler

Comment: no there iam having iam getting id of another table

Comment: actually my problem is iam not getting the corresponding id of that table